# Getting data out of Coinmarketcap API with PHP not working

Tags: php, arrays, json, api, curl

I am trying get data out of the API of Coinmarketcap. The specific coin I want data of is written in the URL. When I run my code I get an error/notice message:

> Trying to get property of non-object in

```
$url = "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/vertcoin/";

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$data = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

$parsed_json = json_decode($data);

$coindata = $parsed_json->{'price_usd'};
```

Comment: What do you see if you add print_r($parsed_json);

Comment: if `$parsed_json` is not an object, that means `json_decode($data)` failed. Check whether `$data` is in fact a valid JSON string, and find out which error `json_last_error()` gives you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API response gives you an array so you need to do this:

```
$coindata = $parsed_json['0']->price_usd;
```

This gives you the value of price_usd within the first element of the array.